# Can I generate I/O activity with a max (throttled) throughput?

Tags: linux, performance, hard-drive

For example, is there a tool or method where I can say (for example) "generate up to 50 MB/s of read activity to this file, but no greater"? Or configure a tiny delay between read operations, which could have basically the same effect? I have a specific need to create an I/O workload that's more deterministic than a normal dd or disk stress test. I'm looking for something that works in Linux...

Comment: 'iozone'? 'fio'? have you tried them?

Comment: So far I've found the "thinktime" parameter in fio, and the idea of using rsync with --bwlimit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [cpipe](http://cpipe.berlios.de/) with -s option.

```
cat /dev/zero | cpipe -s 50000 > /testfile
cat /testfile | cpipe -s 50000 > /dev/null
```

Comment: Nice suggestion. I was not familiar with that program.